# How to multiply my list by each number of it (mini calculator)

Tags: python, list, tuples, calculator

I've searched in google and python documentation and Stackoverflow and I got really confused and no ways of using anything has proven to be correct.

```
divisors = []


prime_numbers = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]        
first_fraction_number = int(input("Type the first number of your fraction " + prompt))
second_fraction_number = int(input("Type the second number of your fraction " + prompt))

        for i in range(len(prime_numbers)):

            if first_fraction_number%prime_numbers[i-1]==0:
                divisors.append([prime_numbers[i-1]])
                #divisors = divisors + prime_numbers[i-1]

            elif second_fraction_number%prime_numbers[i-1]==0:
                divisors.append([prime_numbers[i-1]])
                #divisors = divisors + prime_numbers[i-1]

        #mmc_number = operator.mul(divisors,1)



        mmc_number = 1

        divisors = (str(divisors).replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",",""))
        print (divisors)

        len_div = len(divisors)
        #divisors = list(map(int,divisors))

        for i in range(0,len_div):



            if type((divisors[i])) == int:

                print("Test")
```

I know my code have alot of mistakes, because I don't know how to do this ...

I've tried:

```
print(reduce(operator.mul, divisors[]))
```

and did not work too.

```
print(reduce(mul, map(int, divisors)))
```

neither.

Example of what i need :
If divisors = [2,3,5] , I need mmc_number = 2*3*5

Comment: When did you define the variables `first_fraction_number` and `second_fraction_number`?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: Up in my code, did not posted them here ... sorry ... they are input from prompt @Stendika

Comment: @jonrsharpe the problem is that i don't know how to do this, and always mess with syntax

Comment: Maybe im complicating it too much ?

Comment: @Stephenloky that isn't a precise description of this specific problem. You should provide the information requested; if you get a `SyntaxError`, for example, *provide the traceback*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to remove the `[]` after `divisors`.

```
divisors = ["2","3","5"]
from operator import mul
print(reduce(mul, map(int, divisors)))   # 30
```

If [divisors is `2 5 7`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856709/how-to-multiply-my-list-by-each-number-of-it-mini-calculator/21856757#comment33087345_21856757), you should do the following

```
divisors = "2 5 7"
from operator import mul
print(reduce(mul, map(int, divisors.split())))   # 70
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "super_program.py", line 448, in <module>
    print(reduce(mul, divisors, 1))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'` I tested it, and this is the result

Comment: @Stephenloky Looks like you have a list of strings. Please try the updated version.

Comment: I've tested and did not work `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "super_program.py", line 442, in <module>
    mmc_number = reduce(mul, map(int, divisors))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '`

Comment: for clarification , when I give `first_fraction_number = 10 and second_fraction_number = 7` the `print(divisors)` = `2 5 7`

Comment: @Stephenloky Now you are simply keeping me guessing. Can you please show me the type of data in `divisors`?

Comment: I've added on another comment

Comment: OMG It Works ! Im so happy ! thanks for sharing ... and why i get downvote ? lol accepted answer ! sorry for complicating :D Now I have a calculator

Comment: Alternatively, instead of converting `divisors` to a string just for printing and then `split`int back to a list, just do `print(' '.join(map(str, divisors)))`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps casting them from string to int is what's needed:

```
divisors = [2,3,5]
from operator import mul
print(reduce(mul, int(divisors)))   # 30
```